# Notice: Array to string conversion from function i couldnt get the answer from other questions

Tags: php, arrays, string

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\dysway\manager\offices.php on line 128
Array

```
 <td><?=get_office_status($results[$count]->office_status)?></td>
```

ive been trying to create a function to get a name from an array and it gets its translation from  a lang file

`<td><?=$results[$count]->office_status?></td>`

displays 1 in that case with out the function,

```
 $offices = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dw_offices");
 $count = $offices->count();
 $results = $offices ->results();
```

but as i try

```
(!function_exists('get_office_status')) {
    function get_office_status(){
    global  $lang;
    return Array
    (
        1 => array( 1,$lang['head']),
        2 => array( 2,$lang['branch']),
    );
  }
}
```

the functionn with array im trying to create

```
$lang = array();

$lang = array_merge($lang,array(
 "head"             => "Head",
 "branch"           => "Branch",
));
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to BangingHeads @ https://discordapp.com/channels/366617046995304448/573110025321709568

```
if(!function_exists('get_office_status')) {
    function get_office_status(){
    global  $lang;
    return Array
    (
        1 => $lang['head'],
        2 => $lang['branch']
    );
  }
}
```